# mwlFlatpickr it's not letting you select the field - Angular

Tags: angular

I have an input that according to the documentation should work

```
<input class="form-control"
type="text"
mwlFlatpickr
[(ngModel)]="dateTimeValue"
[value]="dateTimeValue"
[enableTime]="true"
dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
formControlName="data"
placeholder="Not set"
/>
```

but this is the view I have

[image]

I can't click. Is this guy https://github.com/mattlewis92/angularx-flatpickr#installation

I imported into the module and my package.json

[image]

I'm working with angular-calendar and I need to get the date and time to create an event

Comment: try to upgrade angularx-flatpickr to 6.6.0